# Exclude the word matched in email or URL when using JavaScript regular expression match full word

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to figure out the JavaScript Regular Expression to match the full word only but exclude the word if it is part of email or URLs.

For example, we have text 
Below is my codes

```
var str ='
    this is my myname
    my email is myname@email.com
    another email is support@myname.com
    and my site is www.myname.com.au';


        function match(text, str) {
            var pattern = "(?=\\s|^|\\b)(?:" + text + ")(?=\\s|$|\\b)";
            var regexp = new RegExp(pattern, "ig");
            while ((match = regexp.exec(str)) != null) {
                var offsetStart = parseInt(match.index);
                var offsetEnd   = parseInt(regexp.lastIndex);
                var selectText  = match.toString();
                console.log("offset start " + offsetStart + " offset end " + offsetEnd + " matched text " + selectText);
            }
        }

    match('myname', str);
```

What I want is I want match the text 'myname' in line 1 , exclude the text 'myname@email.com', 'support@myname.com' and 'www.myname.com.au'.

Thanks,

Comment: Use a negative lookahead that matches the things you want to exclude.

Comment: your function returns nothing. what should it return?

Comment: call function match('myname').

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't a robust solution but it could be assumed as a good starting point.

```js
var str =`
    this is my myname
    my email is myname@email.com
    another email is support@myname.com
    and my site is www.myname.com.au`;
    
const matches = str.match(/myname(?!\w*[@.])/g);

console.log(matches)
```